# How can I make jquery rotation thumbnails jquery image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I want to make Jquery image gallery with rotation thumbnils. But I only want to show only 4 thumbnils first. After 4 image complete rotation, next 4 thumbnils up to top.
My coding is in here, How can I change my coding?

```
jQuery('#vcarousel').jcarousel({
    //if(jQuery('#jcarousel-item').attr("jcarouselindex") > 4) {
    vertical: true,
    //wrap: 'last',
    animation: 3000,
    //scroll: rotData.length,
    auto: 4,
    wrap: 'last',
    scroll: 4,
    visible: 4,
    initCallback: vcarousel_initCallback
    //}
});​
```

Or anybody have sample for this one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have utilised your code (or something very close to it) and the jCarousel demo resources to create a jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/nRQ4g/1/

It appears to be working as expected.

If you have an expectation for some different behaviour, if you can either update your question, or add comments here, detailing what should be happening, it will help us help you.

Comment: thank Lucanos for your help. But I don't want to auto rotation. I want only rotate after selected 4 image displayed.E.g website is http://www.tn3gallery.com/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I want only rotate after selected 4 image displayed". I have looked at the website provided, but cannot understand from that either.

Comment: Sorry I made confuse to you. please see this jquery gallery banner http://www.plus.com.sg/index.shtm
In this one, please look at selected border, after it is over 4 box, you cannot see this orange color selected border. Because I cannot move up to top. I want to move up to top after 4 selected box is done. thanks

Comment: I am still not completely sure I understand you, but try http://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/nRQ4g/3/